# Firewall Benchmark- Concurrent connection metrics

Tags: firewall, testing, performance

I intend to perform a Firewall Benchmark. I have reviewed related research papers and RFCs to create a suitable methodology. I have also examined open-source tools useful for the project (iperf, netperf, hping, tcpreply etc).

Many sources, such as RFC3511, recommend to use the maximum number of concurrent TCP connection, as one of the metrics. I was wondering if anybody knows how to obtain the metrics?

Thanks, Luke

Comment: A lot depends on the kind of firewall.  What brand(s) and model(s) are you looking at?

Comment: In a professional setting,  most people select tools from Ixia or Spirent to run the test.  While you can use free tools, support is limited for them, and you must rely on your own expertise to conduct the test.  Many professional test tools include standard RFC tests with them;  you just configure the firewall and run the canned test.

Comment: Well, I intend to conduct the experiment, as part of my degree, so I do not have access to commercial software.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

For metrics you can look in to the reports that NSS labs are publishing, they have pretty solid documentation on how they do firewall testing. You can also google for their reports, sometimes firewall vendors publish them free of charge on their own web page for promo purposes.

As for what tool you need you can use the ones you have listed, but it boils down to the size of the firewall you are planning to test. For a beefy firewall you will most likely need several servers to create a load where you can see the limits of the device. I have done testing with hping and iperf, which are ok for testing plain throughput. However if you want to test for example IPS catch rate or application control, a dedicated test device would be easiest choice by far. You can also rent the test devices, although the rent isn’t cheap by all means either.

One thing to note is that firewall throughput is heavily influenced by the control you have in place, basic firewalling is always fast, but when you turn on antivirus, IPS, SSL-inspection and application control the throughput drops dramatically with all vendors. Try to take this in to account also when making the test plan.